# Одновременная поддержка нескольких сессий в Spring

Tags: java, база-данных, веб-программирование, spring, hibernate

Здравствуйте все!
У меня такой вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы в веб-приложение могли одновременно заходить и пользоваться сразу несколько пользователей (мультисессионность, по моему это называется) как при запуске на локалхосте так и уже при развертке на удаленном сервере. Если да, то как это сделать средствами **Spring** ибо мое веб-приложение разработано с применением этого фреймворка + **Hibernate**? Сам так и не нашел нужную информацию.

Неплохо было бы предоставить пример в **XML** варианте, ибо на данном этапе я пользуюсь именно этим способом описания конфигурации для фреймворков.

**P.S.** Вопрос по теме. Нужно ли что-то менять в этом параметре **hibernate.cfg.xml** или можно оставить как есть?

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: в Spring MVC это из коробки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В spring-mvc это реализовано из коробки. Все должно работать как есть.

А на тему параметра pool_size это вроде как размер пула коннектов к базе, слабо относится к основному вопросу, но можно поставить для верности 5-10, этого вам будет более чем достаточно.

Comment: Я развернул приложение на localhost:8080 и у меня не получается залогиниться в разных вкладках под разными юзерами и пользоваться в таком режиме приложением. Если я на одной вкладке зайду под одним пользователем, то все остальные вкладки тоже перейдут на последнего залогининого пользователя. Так что может быть средства для решения этой проблемы может и даны из коробки но я не знаю как правильно все настроить и прошу дать пример в XML варианте.

Comment: @IngeniousTom То что вы заходите из разных вкладок - не делает ровным счетом никакой погоды. Сессия то у вас одна.

дайте шанс spring-mvc оправдаться и попробуйте логиниться под другими юзерами в  инкогнито-режиме хрома или другом браузере. т.е. одна вкладка в хроме, одна в инкогнито, одна в другом браузере и проверьте результат.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы сессий было много, чтобы можно было логиниться в разных вкладках одного браузера? Меня именно это интересует.

Comment: @IngeniousTom у вас несколько пользователей будут в разных вкладках одного браузера сидеть, я правильно понял?

Comment: @IngeniousTom не зная деталей приложения мне, конечно, сложно судить, но мне кажется, вы идете не верным путем. Подобных решений в рамках spring мне не известно. если дадите чуть больше информации о проекте, думаю вам смогут помочь.

Comment: Несколько вкладок разных пользователей например проще для тестирования приложения, чтобы лишний раз не заливать на сервер ибо долго это. В "Вконтакте" я вот например могу так заходить и хотел бы чтоб мое веб-приложение так же могло. Но раз вы не знаете такой фичи буду искать дальше!

Comment: @IngeniousTom минуточку, в "вконтакте" вы можете логиниться под несколькими людьми в разных вкладках своего браузера?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38860/discussion-between-victor-and-ingenioustom).

Comment: Виноват - такой возможности нет оказывается и в вк. Тогда буду просто тестить в разных браузерах. Спасибо за ответ!